# MissForest imputation (with binary target variable): The response has five or fewer unique values. Are you sure you want to do regression?

Tags: random-forest, data-imputation

i want to impute a dataset with about 250 cases (about 150 NA in the target-Variable).

The target-variable is the amount a machine is used and there are some predictors like production-costs, co-workers and so on.

A machine can be used zero times as well.

I broke down the imputation in 2 steps.

1. Step
   Decide if a machine was used or not: This is a binary
   variable. It is 0 if the machine was not used at all and it is 1 if
   it was used. In this step my target-variable is binary.  I am using
   missForest to do the imputation and i get this Warning:

   > 1: In randomForest.default(x = obsX, y = obsY, ntree = ntree, mtry =
   > mtry,  :   The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure
   > you want to do regression?

   The data-set for missForest consists out of 6 variables (one beeing
   the target and the others are predictors, some categorial and some
   metric).

   I get imputated values and they do not look bad at all, but still it
   would be great to know what causes this warning?

   I use the missForest function with the default parameters and the
   target-variable is set as a factor.
2. Step
   If a machine was predicted as a used one in Step 1, predict
   how often it was used.  Basically its the same imputation like in
   Step 1 but only containing machines that got used. In this case the
   target-variable is metric but i do get the same warning as in Step 1.

   I have no idea what causes the problems?  Could it be that i
   want to create to many random trees (500 is the default value) from
   too little variables?

As a little side-question. I've decided to use this 2-step process because a 1-step process predicted to few machines being not used at all.
I do not understand why this 2 versions deliver so different results?

Comment: They usually do that when the data is a factor and you’re treating it like it is continuous. You might want to double check that you have your variable typing consistent.